# automatic logout from simple-ember-auth/oauth2-server after inactivity

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js, oauth2-server

I have implemented a simple-ember-auth on the front and oauth2-server on the back, using password and refresh_token grants. When the authorisation token is about to expire (this time is set on the server), simple-ember-auth issues a refresh token request, and gets a new authorisation token.

That's cool, however, I need to automatically invalidate the session after a certain inactivity time. Currently, OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator seems to issue the token refresh request ad infinitum.

I would welcome any suggestions or thoughts how to implement this.

Comment: Why not just call `.invalidate()` yourself?

Comment: @Lux I would gladly do that. How do I detect inactivity ?

Comment: Did you considered to disable autorefresh by setting [`refreshAccessTokens: false`](https://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator.html).

Comment: @eight thats the problem, you can't. Or well the question is: what is activity for you? Mouse movement? clicks? transitions? But this is probably a more general JS question, not an `ember` or `ember-simple-auth` question: What is inactivity in a browser and how to detect it?

Comment: @jelhan: I started with that scenario: in it, the user is kicked off regardless of her activity.

Answer (score 4):

As @Lux mentioned in comment you have to implement a user activity detection. You could observe events like `keypress`, `mousemove`, `scroll` etc. on `window` element therefore. If it's not about activity but just if the page is on focus you could consider [Page Visibilty Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API). If it's more about interaction with your application perhaps observe ember events like transitions.

Use [`Ember.debounce`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce) to call OAuth2PasswordGrantAuthenticator `invalidate()` method only if there wasn't any user activity.

Maybe best implemented in a [Application Instance Initializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/initializers/#toc_application-instance-initializers).

Something like this (not tested):

```
// app/instance-initializers/logout-if-inactive.js
export function initialize(applicationInstance) {
  var session = applicationInstance.lookup('service:session');
  var logoutAfter = 15 * 60 * 1000 // in milliseconds
  var logout = function() {
    Ember.run.debounce(session, 'invalidate', logoutAfter);
  }
  window.onmouseevent = logout;
  window.onkeypress = logout;
}

export default {
  name: 'logout-if-inactive',
  after: 'session',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Comment: This worked for me I just had to change `after: 'session'` to `after: 'ember-simple-auth'`.

Comment: Just a quick question : Does it works when two tabs are open ? I suppose the user will be kicked after 15 minutes if he don't click on the other tab, right ?

Comment: Suggested solution does not support multiple tabs yet. Therefore activity state must be shared between windows. You should use same technique as for session store to avoid edge cases. Don't call `session.invalidate` directly in debounce. Use another function which first checks that there wasn't any activity from another tab.